# Error: The variable name '@Provision' has already been declared

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2005

I have a `checkedlistbox`, `textbox` and `combobox` in my form. I'm getting this error: -

```
The variable name '@Provision' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.
Must declare the scalar variable "@BloodGroup".
```

It worked fine before when I didn't use the for loop for my `checkedlistbox`. When using the for loop, my `combobox` `BloodGroup`, got an error.

```
string insert = "INSERT INTO Employee(EmpID, EmpName, Address, Provision, BloodGroup) VALUES (@EmpID, @EmpName, @Address, @Provision, @BloodGroup)";

SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(insert, sqlCon);

comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtEmpID.Text;
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtName.Text;
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", SqlDbType.Text).Value = txtAdd.Text;

for (int a = 0; a < chkProvision.Items.Count; a++)
{
    if (chkProvision.GetItemChecked(a))
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Provision", SqlDbType.Char).Value = chkProvision.Items[a].ToString();
    else
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Provision", "");
}          

if (cbBlood.SelectedValue == null)
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BloodGroup", "");
else
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BloodGroup", SqlDbType.Char).Value = cbBlood.SelectedItem.ToString();

comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

When I change the position where my for loop comes after the SqlCommand, then it throws error on EmpID: -

```
Must declare the scalar variable "@EmpID".
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do if `chkProvision` has multiple selected items? Add multiple rows? And what version of SQL Server? (Actually looks like your schema is wrong. There should be another table with `EmpID,Provision` if an Employee can have multiple.

Comment: BTW: at your string insert is by Values at the End, one Comma without Parameter

Comment: Yes, sorry.. typing error

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2005. chkProvision will save checkeditems in one column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have

```
for (int a = 0; a < chkProvision.Items.Count; a++)
{
    if (chkProvision.GetItemChecked(a))
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Provision", SqlDbType.Char).Value = chkProvision.Items[a].ToString();
    else
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Provision", "");
}
```

so tend to add `@Provision` multiple times.
It's not possible

Query engine have to *uniquely* identify every column that has to be updated, so you can not have the same column multiple times in the same parametric query.

*If there are multiple Provisions per item, so you multiple rows with different provisions, you have to execute query multiple time: one per provision type. Or, create a storedprocedure on server, where you pass the main record and list of Provisions associated with them, and SP does the stuff.*